# Airflow Logs Not Showing in CloudWatch for ECS Deployment

Tags: logging, airflow, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

**Description:**

I'm encountering an issue with Airflow when deploying it on AWS ECS and using CloudWatch for remote logs. Specifically, for some of our DAGs, the logs are not showing up in CloudWatch. Additionally, the DAGs are marked as "Done" immediately after starting.

```bash
ip-10-0-53-198.eu-central-1.compute.internal
*** Reading remote log from Cloudwatch log_group: airflow-dags-logs-48999c6 log_stream: dag_id=company_data_import/run_id=scheduled__2023-08-30T00_00_00+00_00/task_id=company_data_import/attempt=1.log.
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,329] Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: company_data_import.company_data_import scheduled__2023-08-30T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,329] 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,329] Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,329] 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,342] Executing <Task(PythonOperator): company_data_import> on 2023-08-30 00:00:00+00:00
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,347] Started process 539 to run task
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,351] Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'company_data_import', 'company_data_import', 'scheduled__2023-08-30T00:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '72', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/example/dag/data_import.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp9c72jyt7']
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,351] Job 72: Subtask company_data_import
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,556] Running <TaskInstance: company_data_import.company_data_import scheduled__2023-08-30T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host ip-10-0-53-198.eu-central-1.compute.internal
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,636] Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=example.owner@company.de
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=company_data_import
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=company_data_import
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-08-30T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2023-08-30T00:00:00+00:00
# !!! there should be logs here !!!
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,637] Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,652] Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=company_data_import, task_id=company_data_import, execution_date=20230830T000000, start_date=20230907T101609, end_date=20230907T101609
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,802] Task exited with return code 0
[2023-09-07 10:16:09,853] 2 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Here are the details of our setup:

We have deployed Airflow on AWS ECS.
We are using CloudWatch for remote logs.
Each DAG run corresponds to a CloudWatch Log Stream, and these streams are created but logs are not written to them for some reason.

Environment variables:

```yaml
 airflowEnvs:
        description: All environment variables to setup and run Airflow. For application specific envs see `airflowAppConfig`.
        default:
            _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
            _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
            AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session"
            AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: "CeleryExecutor"

            AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING: "true"
            AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID: "logs_cloudwatch"
            AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_CONFIG_CLASS: "dags.settings.LOGGING_CONFIG"
            AIRFLOW__LOGGING__ENCRYPT_S3_LOGS: "false"

            AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: "Europe/Berlin"
            AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
            AIRFLOW__CORE__MIN_SERIALIZED_DAG_UPDATE_INTERVAL: "600"
            AIRFLOW__CORE__MIN_SERIALIZED_DAG_FETCH_INTERVAL: "600"
            AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL: "600"
            AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__SCHEDULER_IDLE_SLEEP_TIME: "5"
            AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__PARSING_PROCESSES: "2"
            AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE: "Europe/Berlin"
            AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__CATCHUP_BY_DEFAULT: "False"
            AIRFLOW_REST_API_USER: django
```

We believe it has something to do with our Logging config. This is our dags.settings.LOGGING_CONFIG:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from airflow.config_templates.airflow_local_settings import DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG


LOGGING_CONFIG = deepcopy(DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG)

LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers']['console'] = {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }

LOGGING_CONFIG['formatters']['default'] = {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        }

LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers']['zeep.xsd.types.simple'] = {  # Especially needed for the DAG in question
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'CRITICAL',
        }
```

Unfortunately we are not abel to pinpoint the issue. We dont think it has something to do with permissions as a cloudwatch logstream is being generated correctly, and other DAGs also show logs. Has anyone experienced something similar?